# How to combine multiple queries of different time range in one table scan

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a big table (millions of rows) with spent statistics.

table def:
 provider_id,
 spent,
 date

most of the providers work monthly so i can do single monthly spent query to get their spent for this time in the month.

```
select provider_id,sum(spent) from spent_table where date >= '20131201' group by 1;
```

However some providers dosnt work monthly , so i need to get their spent for a custom period.
In order to get all custom providers spent i do union query:

```
select provider_id,sum(spent) from spent_table where date between '20130930' and '20140101' and provider_id = 272 group by 1  
union
select provider_id,sum(spent) from spent_table where date between '20130730' and '20131201' and provider_id = 273 group by 1
```

Each select do an index scan ,but i have 50 custom providers so the union query execute as 50 index scan queries.
Is there anything i can do in order to do this in single scan ?

plan is :

```
HashAggregate  (cost=122297336.47..122297337.03 rows=56 width=12)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..122297336.19 rows=56 width=12)
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.00..2428542.88 rows=1 width=12)
               ->  Index Scan using date_idx on spent_table  (cost=0.00..2428448.33 rows=18908 width=12)
                     Index Cond: ((provider_id = 272) AND (date >= '2013-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date < '2014-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.00..2428542.88 rows=1 width=12)
               ->  Index Scan using date_idx on spent_table  (cost=0.00..2428448.33 rows=18908 width=12)
                     Index Cond: ((provider_id = 262) AND (date >= '2013-09-30 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date < '2014-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always grouping by `provider_id`, and each query has a different `provider_id` in its `WHERE` clause.
This means you **can be sure** that the result of each query is discrete, and you can simply combine all the conditions to a single `WHERE` clause with `OR`s:

```
SELECT   provider_id, sum(spent)
FROM     spent_table 
WHERE    (date BETWEEN '20130930' AND '20140101' AND provider_id = 272) OR
         (date BETWEEN '20130730' AND '20131201' AND provider_id = 273)
GROUP BY provider_id
```